# Visual Studio видит math.h, хотя я не подключал. C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Я думаю, у многих проблема в том, что заголовочные файлы visual studio не видит. У меня наоборот. Видит, то что я не хотел. Произошло это после обновления на новую версию.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a1, a2, a3, a4;
    cin >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4;
    cout << (int)sqrt(min(a1, a2) + min(a3, a4));
}
```

Данный код работает, хотя не должен: функция `sqrt()` не должна быть определена так, как я не подключил `math.h`. Хотя если отключить допустим `algorithm`, то функцию `min()` он не видит.

В чем может быть проблема? Я в настройках проекта вроде ничего не менял.

[image: основные настройки компоновщика]
[image: дополнительные]

Comment: [Does <algorithm> include <cmath>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29454488/5045688)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видите ли, в стандарте оговорено, что *должно содержаться* в том или ином заголовочном файле, а не чего в нем *не должно* быть.

Поэтому в конкретном компиляторе один заголовочный файл может потянуть другой. Что не отменяет необходимости для переносимости включать нужный файл...